# Swift PNChart PNCircleChart with Storyboard

Tags: ios, swift

I'm trying to set up a basic PNChart PNCircleChart on my app. I created a UIView in the storyboard and set the class to `PNCircleChart`. The restoration ID is `piechart`. I created an outlet in to my view controller that looks like:

`@IBOutlet weak var pie: PNCircleChart!`

Now I'm trying to build a basic piechart in my viewdidload and I can't figure out how.

```
pie.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
pie.setValue(50, forKey: "A")
pie.setValue(50, forKey: "B")
pie.strokeChart()
```

It is failing with a NSUnkownKeyException error. Any idea how to do this in swift

Answer (score 0):

The `NSUnknownKeyException` is almost always caused when one of your interface elements was hooked up to a property in your view controller that you then deleted.  The property was deleted from the view controller, but the interface builder was never unhooked from that property.

The actual exception message should tell you what "key" it's having trouble finding, which should give you a hint as to which UI element is hooked up wrong.

Once you figure out which key is hooked up wrong, go through your UI elements and right click on each of them.  One of them will be hooked up to a property of this name (and it won't exist in your class source code file).  You need to either click the X for this connection to delete the connection, or you need to add the property back to your source code file.